# write lines of file in another file in python

Tags: python, csv

I want write lines from `input_file` in `output1_file` but when I run my program it doesn't write the first line to the output file.

```
import csv    

from statistics import mean
from typing import TextIO 

def calculate_averages(input_file_name, output_file_name):
with (open(input_file_name, 'r')) as fin:
    line=fin.readline()
    while line:
        line = fin.readline()
        with open (output_file_name,'a') as f:
            f.write((line.strip()))
            f.write('\n')
            f.close()
    line = fin.readline()
return f
calculate_averages('input.csv', 'output1.csv')
```

and my input_file is:

```
mandana,5,7,3,15
hamid,3,9,4,20,9,1,8,16,0,5,2,4,7,2,1
sina,19,10,19,6,8,14,3
sara,0,5,20,14
soheila,13,2,5,1,3,10,12,4,13,17,7,7
ali,1,9
sarvin,0,16,16,13,19,2,17,8
```

but my output1_file is:

```
 hamid,3,9,4,20,9,1,8,16,0,5,2,4,7,2,1
 sina,19,10,19,6,8,14,3
 sara,0,5,20,14
 soheila,13,2,5,1,3,10,12,4,13,17,7,7
 ali,1,9
 sarvin,0,16,16,13,19,2,17,8
```

the first line is missing.

Comment: Please drop all the exclamation marks, they detract from what you're asking.

Comment: Get rid of `line=fin.readline()`, that's discarding the first line

Comment: You can just loop over the file... `for line in fin` without the read-ahead, `while` and read again thing.... You also don't need to close the file within the `with` block and you don't want to be opening it multiple times either (per each line)... open it once along with your input file with `a` mode if absolutely required and then use that.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `line` in your first `line=fin.readline()` is overwritten by the next `line=fin.readline()` before it is written to the output file.

You should instead use a `for` loop to iterate of the file object as an iterator:

```
def calculate_averages(input_file_name, output_file_name):
    with open(input_file_name, 'r') as fin, open(output_file_name,'a') as f:
        for line in fin:
            f.write(line.strip() + '\n')
```

Comment: Presumably the OP will do something with `mean` at some point... but otherwise you can even side step the for-loop and do `f.writelines(line.strip() + '\n' for line in fin)`...

Answer (score 0):

Because you called `readline` twice before the first write.

Some tips:

1, No need to use `f.close()` when open file with `with` statement.

2, No need to return `f`.

Below is the code I refactored.

```
import csv

from statistics import mean
from typing import TextIO


def calculate_averages(input_file_name, output_file_name):
    with open(input_file_name, 'r') as fin:
        line = fin.readline()
        with open(output_file_name, 'a') as f:
            while line:
                f.write((line.strip()))
                f.write('\n')
                line = fin.readline()


calculate_averages('input.csv', 'output1.csv')
```